# does solidity round decimals to ceil or floor them?

Tags: solidity

so lets say result of a calculation in solidity is `0.2` or `0.8`, when I save that result in a variable does that convert to `0` or `1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solidity truncates all results, it's equivalent to the floor operation. So if your contract tries to store the result of `9 / 5` in a `uint` it will simply store `1`

Comment: For stake of completeness: are negative numbers floored as well, or are they rounded towards zero?

Comment: Negative numbers are rounded up towards zero: `-4 / 3` => `-1`

Comment: source https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#division